# How To Pass "this" to a Function in a Nested .each() loop within a .getJSON() method

Tags: jquery, json, scope, this, each

So I know what the problem is, but I don't know the proper way (the syntax) to fix it.

If you take the code from "myFunction" and put it inside the .each loop where I am calling "myFunction" then my code works because "this" is being defined and is within the scope of the JSON object that I am referencing.

But, when I write my function and declare it outside the scope of the JSON object, then it no longer knows what "this" is and returns a value of "undefined".

How do I pass "this" as an argument to my function so that I can properly grab the values?

```
    $.getJSON('labOrders.json', function(json) {
    var aceInhibitors = "",
        antianginal = "",
        anticoagulants = "",
        betaBlocker = "",
        diuretic = "",
        mineral = "",
        myFunction = function () {
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='row drugLineItem'>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns moneydot' style='background:none;'></div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns drugTitleWrap'>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='row drugTitle'>"+this.name+"</div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='row drugDose'>"+this.strength+"</div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns'></div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns orderDeets dxRefill'>"+this.refills+"</div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns orderDeets dxPillCount'>"+this.pillCount+"</div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns orderDeets dxSig'>"+this.sig+"</div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns orderDeets dxRoute'>"+this.route+"</div>",
            aceInhibitors += "<div class='columns orderDeets drugTab'>"+this.dose+"</div>"
        }

  $.each(json.medications, function(index, orders) {
    $.each(this.aceInhibitors, function() {
        myFunction();

    });
    $.each(this.antianginal, function() {

    });
  });

  $('#loadMedSections').append(aceInhibitors);



});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

```
 $.each(this.aceInhibitors, myFunction);
```

There's no need for the wrapper function, and that would have the correct context.

Second option:

```
$.each(this.aceInhibitors, function() {
    myFunction.call(this);
});
```

That will call it will the context of the context of the wrapper function.

Comment: Thanks! the call method worked! Will give check when timer is done!

Comment: Unless you need the wrapper function for some reason, I would remove it.  The first option presented is much cleaner and functionally equivalent.  Glad it works though.

Comment: It's what I call the idiom of using a function for the sole purpose of executing a different function.  Basically, I consider: `function() { f(); }` a wrapper function of the function f.  With `var w = function() { f(); };`, `w()` is essentially equivalent to `f()` except for the context (`this`) will be that of `w` instead of the actual caller.  (w's `this` will be the caller of `w` and `f`'s `this` will essentially reference `w`.  Basically, you're wrapping the execution of `f` in `w` for no reason, thus hiding the actual context of execution.

Comment: Ahh....gotcha....But I couldn't get this to work without the wrapper function...By including the named function as an argument in the each function, what is invoking the function to fire?? Or do I need to remove the wrapping function syntax for the function to fire first?

Comment: I was right....I had to remove the wrapping function for your first solution to work. Thanks so much! I appreciate the chat!

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `call`, which allows you to set an explicit value for `this`.

If you do the following for example:

```
myFunction.call(someobject);
```

then `myFunction` will be called with `this = someobject`.

In your case you can probably do:

```
$.each(this.aceInhibitors, function() {
  myFunction.call(this); // will use the current value of "this" inside myFunction as well.
});
```